# How to filter Okta Applications by profile via Okta SDK or Okta API

Tags: okta, okta-api

I would like to know how can I filter Okta Applications by Profile value.

Lets say my Application JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "oidc_client",
    "label": "Sample Client profile",
    "signOnMode": "OPENID_CONNECT",
    "credentials": {
      "oauthClient": {
        "token_endpoint_auth_method": "client_secret_post"
        }
    },
    "profile": {
        "source": "test"
        },
    "settings": {
      "oauthClient": {
        "client_uri": "http://localhost:8080",
        "logo_uri": "http://developer.okta.com/assets/images/logo-new.png",
        "redirect_uris": [
          "https://example.com/oauth2/callback",
          "myapp://callback"
        ],
        "response_types": [
          "token",
          "id_token",
          "code"
        ],
        "grant_types": [
          "implicit",
          "authorization_code"
        ],
        "application_type": "native"
      }
    }
}' "https://${yourOktaDomain}/api/v1/apps"
```

I would like to get a list of Applications that profile["Source"] is "test". Is there a way to filter list of Applications via Okta API or Okta SDK?

Comment: you can iterate through all and only take those which match, no?

Comment: Yes I can, but that's not the best way, and not sure what would be the performance when we have too many applications

Comment: as far as I know there is no way to do that through a direct API call